# Why not able to submit a non-rendered form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

Is there a way to submit a non-rendered `form`?

I have specific scenario where I want to submit a dynamic form to the server. As of now I have achieved this by adding `form` to the `body` after creating it using `jQuery`. It works perfectly, but I wonder **why I am not able to submit a `in memory` `form` without rendering into the `DOM`**.

Following is the code snippet I have tried:

```
var action_url = "/post-url";
$(`
  <form action=${action_url} method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="name1" name="name1"/>
    <input type="text" value="name2" name="name2"/>
    <input type="text" value="name3" name="name3"/>
  </form>
`).appendTo('body').submit();
```

So, why I am not able to do like below:

```
var action_url = "/post-url";
$(`
  <form action=${action_url} method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="name1" name="name1"/>
    <input type="text" value="name2" name="name2"/>
    <input type="text" value="name3" name="name3"/>
  </form>
`).submit();
```

When I run the above code getting following warning message in console:

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Comment: Use some virtual dom library to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we attempt to insert elements into the document, it would create some DOM nodes cached by **document fragments** before appending to the document. The nodes cached by document fragments **CAN** register event handlers and also **CAN** be triggered, but `submit()`'s algorithm would be a little different.

DOM nodes in document fragment are **NOT** part of the **active document tree structure** and according to the [HTML standard documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm), if the form is not connected (associated, created or whatever else similar term) to the browsing context(document), the submission process will be canceled.

For further reading:

[Form submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm)

[DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Answer (score 0):

A form should be on the DOM before submission because afterloading page, every element is attached an event so is recognized by the DOM and jquery or javascript can manipulate. but what you are doing (2nd) doesn't even exist in the DOM so the event submit() is not available to it.

Comment: So when I tried the code I have posted in the question, I can see that there is an submit event available for the form element created via jQuery. But when I call submit method getting following message 
`jquery.self.js?body=1:4610 Form submission canceled because the form is not connected` - what exactly this means and why, is my question. 

I will add this info into my question.

Comment: That's what I said it's not connected because it's not attached to the DOM

Comment: Your code is generated after the page has loaded and this form is created dyamically so no event can be submitted unless until you refer to it via is parent as in your first case. Suppose we generate a button in a div.
('.buttonClass').on('click', function(){}) will not work but
('.buttonDivClass').on('click', '.buttonClass', function(){
   var button = $(this);
}) This will work

Comment: If this line
`$('.buttonClass').on('click', function(){})`
will work if we added the element with class ''buttonClass" before this line get executed. In some scenario we will be rendering elements after we define the event listener in that case we needed add as you mentioned below 
`$(document).on('click', '.buttonClass', function(){})`

But in my case I am creating the form element and trying to do this. Like, we can create button in memory and attach events and trigger event for that.

Comment: See this link [link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1204-you-cannot-submit-non-rendered-forms.htm)