# Why does form.submit() do nothing if form is not attached to a document DOM?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I could make a hidden form by `style.display = 'none'`:

```js
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "//test.local/login.php";
form.style.display = 'none';
```

I thought instead of hiding I could leave form out of the document DOM, like removing the line:

```
document.body.appendChild(form);
```

but then:

```
form.submit();
```

does nothing. Why attachment to DOM is required for a form for `submit()` to work?

Comment: Aren't you seeing the error "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" in the console?

Comment: Nothing in the  recent Firefox console.

Comment: Internet Explorer used to be really weird about handling hidden elements as part of form posting; basically it treated them as if they were disabled. How it would respond to an entire form being hidden, I don't know. However, it's an easy problem to solve: if you make the form `position: absolute` and set `left` to something like -10000, then the form is effectively hidden but the browser thinks it is "visible" (not hidden).

Comment: @Pointy The question says that hidden works, disconnected doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar yea I get that, it was just tangentially interesting information. I used to keep a "secreted" class in my CSS to do the "off the screen" thing for inputs that needed to be hidden but not hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification for the method](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-submit) says that it must [submit the form](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-form-submit) which says:

> If form [cannot navigate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#cannot-navigate), then return.

The form can't navigate if the *element is not an a element* (it's a `form`) *and is not [connected](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#connected).* (which it isn't because it is its own root as it hasn't been attached to the document).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the it seems the form has to be connected in some way to the DOM for the event to be valid.

This has been covered in more detail here by [@Hikarunomemory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9561918/hikarunomemory)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49994802/3381067

Comment: If you're just going to post a link to another question, flag it as a duplicate.